# Where to get Flex - Java DS (Blaze) training material?

Tags: java, apache-flex, blazeds, amf, dataservice

I was wondering if any of you out there knows where I can get really good training material (videos, examples, etc) on Flex - Java Data Services (BlazeDS would be ideal) besides the ones offered directly by Adobe. I'm thinking on something like [David Tucker's blog](http://www.davidtucker.net/)

Comment: BlazeDS is opensource. Is there a reason why one should not rely on Adobe's documentation? I'm curious. Or, is it that you already have read all of it?

Comment: Adobe has never done something that would make me think they are unreliable... but I have nothing to compare the material they offer with. So I get really on my skeptic mood when taking decisions based on faith on a particular brand. The bottom line... I read Adobe docs but I would really have something to compare them and enrich whit I can learn from all the possible sources I can get.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is a screencast of a presentation I did about Flex and Java a while back:
http://www.jamesward.com/blog/2008/07/21/video-flex-and-java/

Also, here is an intro to BlazeDS article I co-authored:
http://www.infoq.com/articles/blazeds-intro

Answer (score 3):

[Flex on Java](http://www.manning.com/allmon/) covers BlazeDS in the chapter 5. I haven't read it through properly yet so I cannot tell how good the book is.

Answer (score 3):

Check out [Christophe Coenraets' blog](http://coenraets.org/)

I think he creates the BlazeDS turnkey samples, and he's got some other reference applications on his blog that make use of BlazeDS.

Answer (score 2):

Go on with examples in [Tour de Flex](http://flex.org/tour), its awesome!!!

Answer (score 0):

Here's where you can get [Blaze Training](http://www.hartmannsoftware.com).